# Making NavigationBar subview clickable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a View Controller embedded in Navigation Controller.  The view has 1 `WKWebView`, hence, I'm setting `view = webView` in `loadView()` override.

So, I'm adding a small little sub navigation bar underneath my navigation controller to allow a user to change their location.I can add the subview to the navigation controller, I'm just not able to make it clickable.

```
override func loadView() {
   let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
   config.processPool = YourModelObject.sharedInstance.processPool
   webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
   webView.navigationDelegate = self
   self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self
   view = webView
   ..
   
   if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
      let secondFrame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 44.1, width: navigationBar.frame.width, height: 30)
      let secondLabel = UILabel(frame: secondFrame)
      secondLabel.textColor = .black
      secondLabel.text = "Getting your location..."
      secondLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      let guestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(setLocation(_:)))
      secondLabel.addGestureRecognizer(guestureRecognizer)
      secondLabel.textAlignment = .left
      secondLabel.font = secondLabel.font.withSize(14)
      secondLabel.tag = 1002
      navigationBar.addSubview(secondLabel)
   }
}
```

And then the setLocation function

```
@objc func setLocation(_ sender: Any) {
   print("location label tapped")
}
```

But when I tap the label, I'm not getting anything printed in console. I don't know if the use of `target: self` is wrong for the tapGestureRecognizer or what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I too am new to Swift, so my answer is far from guaranteed. I just know what it's like to be in your position,

Perhaps try creating a subclass of navigationBar for the sub navigation bar, i.e. mySubNavigationBar.  Then in the subclass's code do all the initialization that you need to do. Including the print line so you'll know if you're getting there.

p.s.  I would have put this as a comment, but I don't have enough points to add comments.